# Text always ellipsis in a scrolled element in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have a problem with text always ellipsis in a scrolled element.

When I use:

```
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
```

Firefox ellipsis all items. No matter if the anchor has `display: list-item`, or parent `display: flex, flex-direction: column`. On Chrome everything is working fine.

The difference between chrome and firefox is significant.

[image: chrome and firefox comparasion]

I prepare codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-glade-6kbcq?file=/index.html

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764076. Chrome has similar bugs in other cases.

The reliable fix is to use `overflow-y: scroll`.